# Jquery html() changes my code...?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, dom, dynamic-content

I am getting some html data from `$.ajax` and need to insert them in a `<div></div>`
In some cases, returned `html`, needs to contain another `div`, so the answer is like:

```
info here</div><div>info there
```

Instead of closing the 1st div, it creates this:

```
<div>info here<div>info there</div></div>
```

How can I prevent this?

Comment: What is the jquery code?

Comment: `info here</div><div>info there` is invalid HTML

Comment: Please post more code.

Comment: I don't know how you get that kind of data in response but put your data from response inside div tags.  so `"<div>"+data+"</div>"` will create an opening and a closing div tag for the text you need to display.

Comment: Post more code `info here</div><div>info there is invalid HTML` and also you should have proper Id in `DIV` which you are injecting it in.

Could you explain little more what are you trying to do

Comment: jQuery doesn't edit HTML, it edits the DOM. So before it can insert your code, it needs to turn it into a valid (set of) DOM element(s), which it does by adding the code you've observed. There is no solution, except to attack the problem in a different way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't valid HTML:

```
info here</div><div>info there
```

I doubt it's jQuery doing this.  More likely it's the browser trying to make sense of the invalid markup, correcting it as best it can.  It will do this any time it encounters invalid markup, whether delivered via AJAX or from the initial page load.

You can prevent this from happening by using valid HTML.

**Edit:** Note that in the browser the HTML for the page isn't a raw string (like it is from server-side code).  It's a hierarchical model of document elements.  So the kind of string manipulation you might do server-side to construct HTML doesn't work the same client-side.  You don't want to break up elements by injecting strings between them.  Rather, replace the contents of a parent element.  So in your existing `div` you might insert:

```
$('#parentDiv').html('<div>info here</div><div>info there</div>');
```

Or you might *replace* the entire parent `div` with that markup:

```
$('#parentDiv').replaceWith('<div>info here</div><div>info there</div>');
```

Answer (score 3):

Your could do something like tha

```
$("#mydiv")[0].outerHtml = "<div id='mydiv'>" + data + "</div>";
```

Or:

```
$("#mydiv").replaceWith("<div id='mydiv'>" + data + "</div>");
```

Comment: You beat me on this one.. I gave the same thing in comment.. ;)

Comment: I know,  in fact your answer was posted just before my comment.. so you couldn't...

Answer (score 1):

Post your jquery code, however let me guess you are accessing directly $("div") which selects all div parameters in your document.

Put an id or class on the div you want to change like so:

```
<div id="dynamic_content"></div>
```

-

```
$("#dynamic_content").html("my new dynamic content from ajax request");
```

However, the other possibility, as poster before said is that your html is malformed and jquery is pasting code in the wrong element.